# How to grab url path to file in php

Tags: php, path, dirname, realpath

For sending a link to a email (confirming subscription). i need the path to the file `subscribe.php`.
On my webserver, the file `subscribe.php` is in the webroot.
External access will be: `http://newsletter.mydomain.com/subscribe.php`

This is the link in `subscribe.php` which i send to the user by email:

```
$mail->Body = '<a href="'.$subscribe_path.'subscribe.php?name='.urlencode(base64_encode($name)).'&email='.urlencode(base64_encode($email)).'">Confirm your email</a>';
```

At this moment i use this:

```
$subscribe_path = 'http://newsletter/mydomain.com/'
```

How can i grab the path more generally? 
i tried:

```
$subscribe_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/';
```

but that produces something like `/home/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/newsletter/httpdocs/`

Comment: You are confusing your actual file path with your URL path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file `subscribe.php` put var below:

```
  $subscribe_path = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]";
```

When you echo `$subscribe_path` it will output:
`http://newsletter.mydomain.com/subscribe.php`

Lets say you have `subscribe.php` in a subfolder, named `subfolder`, it will output:

`http://newsletter.mydomain.com/subfolder/subscribe.php`

The link in the email:

```
$mail->Body = '<a href="'.$subscribe_path.'?name='.urlencode(base64_encode($name)).'&email='.urlencode(base64_encode($email)).'">Confirm your email</a>';
```